# How to apply a Javascript action on an element dynamically generated by a partial?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using [Cocoon](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon) to generate nested forms. The partial for those nested forms have a file input, which I'm styling with [bootstrap filestyle](http://markusslima.github.io/bootstrap-filestyle/).

The partial that generates the file input looks like this:

**_image_fields.html.haml**

```
.form-group
  -if f.object.filename?
    .col-md-2
      =image_tag(f.object.filename_url(:thumb))
  .col-md-4
    %p
      =f.file_field :filename
  -if f.object.filename?
    .col-md-2
      %p
        =f.check_box :_destroy
        =f.label :_destroy, 'Remove'
%hr
```

This works fine when the partial is loaded n amount of times in a loop in a previous view, but any block added dynamically using this partial does not get the styling applied.

This is part of my coffescript that loads the pertinent part:

```
ready = ->
  $(':file').filestyle
    buttonText: "Find File"
    buttonBefore: true

$(document).ready(ready)
$(document).on('page:load', ready)
```

How can I bind the styling so that it gets applied to any element dynamically created with a `file` input?

I know how to bind the `onclick` event, but what about just a class and/or element type that has no event, other than on page load?

### EDIT (Progress!):

I managed to make it work by binding to the `DOMNodeInserted` event, with something like this:

```
  $(document).on 'DOMNodeInserted', ->
    $(':file').filestyle
      buttonText: "Find File"
      buttonBefore: true
```

It works, however I have to duplicate my code for the dynamically created file inputs, or in other words my final code looks like this:

```
ready = ->
  $(':file').filestyle
    buttonText: "Find File"
    buttonBefore: true
  $(document).on 'DOMNodeInserted', ->
    $(':file').filestyle
      buttonText: "Find File"
      buttonBefore: true

$(document).ready(ready)
$(document).on('page:load', ready)
```

It's a dirty solution, but it does the job. I'll post an update if I find a better solution.

Comment: Use event delegation https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/ . Sorry I don't use coffee script so I can't give you an exact answer in coffee script. If you want an example I can give you one in jsfiddle

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but they're only mentioning the `click` event. I'm trying to make it so that any file `<input>` tag gets this particular styling, through a Javascript action. Coffescript isn't that different, if you got a solution in javascript, I can work with that.